# How to express "all members of containers of class C must be of class M" in rdfs?

Tags: containers, rdf, semantic-web, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I have these triples (expressed in turtle):

```
:C rdf:subClassOf rdfs:Container.
:M a rdfs:Class.
```

How do i specify that only instances of `:M` can be members of `:C`? I looked through [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_containervocab), but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't express this with an RDFS ontology (that is, as an RDF graph interpreted according to the [RDFS entailment regime](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#rdfs-interpretations)). You can't express this with an OWL DL ontology (that is, an OWL ontology interpreted according to the [OWL direct semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/)). However, it can be expressed with OWL Full (that is, as an RDF graph interpreted according to the [OWL RDF-based semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-rdf-based-semantics/)). In [Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/):

```
[
  a  owl:Restriction;
  owl:onProperty  rdfs:member;
  owl:someValuesFrom  :C
]
rdfs:subClassOf  :M .
```

If you wan't to make it compatible with OWL DL, you must not use RDF containers but you can make your own class of containers:

```
:Container  a  owl:Class .
:C  rdfs:subClassOf  :Container .
:M  a  owl:Class .
:member  a  owl:ObjectProperty .
[
  a  owl:Restriction;
  owl:onProperty  :member;
  owl:someValuesFrom  :C
]
rdfs:subClassOf  :M .
```